# ASP.net InnerException: add record to DB

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, savechanges, inner-exception

Been through my textbook, but I'm still having problems with catching an inner exception as I try to add a record to the database.  What is the proper syntax for catching an InnerException in my class?

The inner expection is being thrown on the **db.SaveChanges**.  Here is the code in my 'addReviews.cs' class file to add the record:

```
  public void addReview(int restId, int timeID, string dateValue, string describe, int cuisineId, int serviceId, int ambianceId, string memberId)
    {
        REVIEW addReview = new REVIEW();
        addReview.REVIEW_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(dateValue);
        addReview.REVIEW_DATE_SUBMITTED = DateTime.Today;
        addReview.REVIEW_DESC = describe;
        addReview.TIME_ID = timeID;
        addReview.REVIEWER_ID = 1;
        addReview.FOOD_ID = cuisineId;
        addReview.SERVCE_ID = serviceId;
        addReview.AMBIENCE_ID = ambianceId;
        addReview.REST_ID = restId;
        addReview.PRICE_ID = 1;

        //Add record to database
        db.AddToREVIEWs(addReview);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```cs
try
{
  db.SaveChanges();
}
catch(ApplicationException exception)
{
   // just log and throw out
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
              String.Concat(
                   "EXCEPTION: ", 
                   exception.ToString));

   if (exception.InnerException != null)
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
               String.Concat(
                  "INNER EXCEPTION: ", 
                  exception.InnerException.ToString));
   }

   throw;
}
```

PS: try to catch more specific exception, in your case it worth to catch `SqlException` as well.

Comment: OMG ... I had made a change to my db and forgot to update my entity model.  Not too swift.  Thanks so much for the help as it will come in handy and I continue on this project.  Regards!!!